# Weird eclipse bug. Code appearing and disappearing.

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

So I'm doing some android development, but every now and again when I modify an XML file or a C file it seems, eclipse tells me I have an error. The code looks fine to me but when I start clicking on my code around the problem area, weird things start happening, code appears out of nowhere and moves about. It's very strange.

The only way I have to found to fix it is to move the code down abit and up and around and saving. Eventually with enough moving about and saving, the eclipse error goes away.

Does anyone have any idea as to what the problem is? It only seems to be happening when I'm using eclipse for android development. It doesn't seem to happen when I'm in any Java files though, only xml and C files so far.

Youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0bFwgdVxyRM

Comment: How recent are your builds of Eclipse and ADT?

Comment: @nitind They are the most recent builds. I actually recently decided to start fresh and download the latest build of everything to try and fix the problem. It did fix some bugs that I previously had but this one still persists.

Comment: Try reinstalling Eclipse.

Comment: @ASG Yeh I tried doing that recently - started from fresh but no luck.